# Difficulty knitting $$

Tags: knitr

I am writing in an RMD code as follows:

```
$$

\text{We start with the following equation}\\
\mu=\lambda*\theta^E*PT\\


\text{The following represents a model for lambda within the context of our question}\\
\lambda=\lambda_0*\theta_1^M*\theta_2^{M_75}*\theta_3^{M_80}*\theta_4^{M_85}*\theta_5^{M2000}*\theta_6^{M2005}*PT\\


\log(\lambda)=log(\lambda_0)+log(\theta_1)*M+log(\theta_2)*M75+log(\theta_3)*M80+log(\theta_4)*M85+log(\theta_5)*M2000+log(\theta_6)*M2005+log(PT)\\


$$
```

In my R studio, I am getting the expected output:

[image: here].

However, when I knit my file to HTML, I get an unexpected output:

[image: here].

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this:

```
$\text{We start with the following equation}\\$
$$\mu=\lambda*\theta^E*PT\\$$

$\text{The following represents a model for lambda within the context of our question}\\$
$$\lambda=\lambda_0*\theta_1^M*\theta_2^{M_75}*\theta_3^{M_80}*\theta_4^{M_85}*\theta_5^{M2000}*\theta_6^{M2005}*PT\\$$

$\text{My big equation}\\$
$$\log(\lambda)=log(\lambda_0)+log(\theta_1)*M+log(\theta_2)*M75+log(\theta_3)*M80+log(\theta_4)*M85+log(\theta_5)*M2000+log(\theta_6)*M2005+log(PT)\\$$
```

*$ - inline formula, $$  - "centered" formula*

[image]

Comment: @Lior133 No problems, you can accept my answer ;)